# await and async switching the order of the functions

Tags: javascript, node.js, async-await, socket.io, puppeteer

I just got a problem with my server NodeJS. I think it has to do with **await/async**

What I want to do is making a system that use Socket to create Email (with nodemailer) from PDF (with puppeteer) and then sending them to an Email adresse.

So I have to create the PDF before sending it by Email.

This is my Code:

```
async function CreatePDF(){ // Fonction cree
      
      console.log('Trying to make the PDF');
      try{
        const browser = await puppeteer.launch();
        const page = await browser.newPage();
    
        await page.setContent('<body><style>' + HeadHTML + '</style>'+ PageHTML + '</body>');
        await page.emulateMedia('screen');
        await page.pdf({
          path: path.join(__dirname, 'Nouveau dossier', NumberOfTheFile + '.pdf'),
          format: "A4",
          printBackground: true
        });
    
        console.log('PDF Created!');
        
        SendEmail(); //Doesn't use async or await
    
      } catch (e)
      {
        console.log('Error: ', e)
      }
    }




function SendEmail(){ 

   console.log('Trying to send the email');

   //Put everything to send Email here.

}
```

The problem is that the PDF is created after the system try to send the email. I don't know if there is a way to make puppeteer work without await/async or if I can make sure that things go in the correct direction.

On the console i get:

> Trying to send the email

> ...

> PDF Created

Comment: I don't think this is possible the console.log calls aren't even in async code.

Comment: Even if all the puppeteer code runs asynchronously, the console logs will be in order.

Comment: If this is actual real code then it's impossible for those console.logs to happen inthe order you claim

Comment: I can assure you that it happened yesterday.Whit the ... saying that the email couldn't be sent. Now I just add a await befor the call of SendEmail() and it kind of works even if that is really slow.